# reference object with key containing brackets

Tags: php

I'm doing a `print_r` on an object that is returned after running a query. Here is my `print_r` log.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [MAX(sort_order)] => 3
)
```

I want to get the value inside `[MAX(sort_order)]` but I cant figure out how to target it from within php.

Like `$sort_order = $object->[MAX(sort_order)];` (I know that won't work)

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why not alias the column in the query, i.e., `MAX(sort_order) as MAX_SORT_ORDER`.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it worked but I was just wondering how one would reference an object in this situation? It was the first time I saw something like this.

Comment: Curly brackets should do the job, too: `$object->{'MAX(sort_order)'};`. Just FYI. Standard PHP syntax. See as well http://cowburn.info/2008/01/12/php-vars-curly-braces/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add this in your query `MAX(sort_order) AS max_sort_order` in your query

Comment: Yes, I did that and it worked but I was just wondering how one would reference an object in this situation? It was the first time I saw something like this.

Comment: In PHP the other to options would be to fetch the query as a numeric array or a associated array, so you could read it as `$result[3];` or `$result['MAX(sort_order)'];` It would be useful to know which method you used to execute the query.

Comment: Hmmm I guess that would work also. Thanks :)